Can't open database in resource
I have a project whose file structure is the following:
   |-Header Files
   |-Sources Files
   | resources


ls -l resources/                                         
total 6388                                                                                                           
-rw------- 1 alain alain    1630 16 mai   20:29 icon.png                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1 alain alain 6537216 16 mai   20:28 pl_db.db       

My .qrc file contains :
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>resources/pl_db.db</file>
    <file>resources/icon.png</file>
</qresource> 
</RCC>

My code is
QSqlDatabase mainDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mainDb.setDatabaseName(":/resources/pl_db.db");
QImage *green = new QImage(":/resources/icon.png");
if(green->isNull()) {
    qDebug("null");
}
else {
    qDebug(" image opened");
}

if(mainDb.open()){
    qDebug() << "Db opened";
} else {
    qDebug() << "db not opened" ;
    qDebug() << mainDb.lastError();
}

Terminal output is
image opened
    db not opened
    QSqlError("14", "Error opening database", "unable to open database file")

If I copy the database file in ~/  and replace
setDatabaseName(":/resources/pl_db.db"); 
with
setDatabaseName(":/home/alain/pl_db.db"); 
the database is correctly opened.
#sqlitebrowser resources/pl_db.db shows that the database file is valid.
I must be making an obvious error, but I  am really unable to catch it. What I am doing wrong here?

I have found out the problem: it is simply not possible to open a database file stored in resources.
As a work around, I create a copy of the database in a temporary file and the open the database.
QFile dbResFile(":/resources/pl_db.db");
QTemporaryFile* tempDb = QTemporaryFile::createNativeFile(dbResFile);
tempDb->open();
QSqlDatabase mainDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mainDb.setDatabaseName(tempDb->fileName());
mainDb.open()

